# Understanding the structure of models in web api services

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have used  web API in single page application and in the local project for several times.
but now I want to know how the users of other companies can understand our model structure while using our we API service,
for example for posting data(post vessel date).how can they understand our structure of vessel class ? should we send our class in separate file to company?
Considering the fact that by adding WCF and web services to the program source, can provide us with the whole structure, such as models, methods and its results, is it logical to use web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a web API help/documentation page that will list all your public APIs along with the parameters,return types etc.

There are 2 ways to do it

1. Web API help page, refer - https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages
2. You can integrate it using swagger, refer- http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

In both the cases you need to annotate your API method with XML comments

Comment: Did this answer your question. If yes please mark it as an answer.